# Some of the pins In my stm32 boards do not work

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, nucleo

I am a beginner in embedded devices. I want to run a blinking my nucleo stm32f303ret6.
here you can see the code that I used for three pins to toggle an led.

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, 1);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15, 1);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, 1);
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, 0);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15, 0);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, 0);
  HAL_Delay(1000);
```

when I wire the circuit on breadboard it works only for pin A10 but it does not work for pins C15,C14,C12. I check some other pins such as C1 and it worked.

why it doesn't work for some pins and doesn't work for some others? does it mean that the problem is with the pins themselves ???

I tried the exact code for several pins and I got different results.

Comment: You need to enable the clock and configure them as outputs

Comment: There is pin setup and stuff required (as the previous commenter mentioned); can you show more of your code on how you did any pin setup?

Comment: Obviously I configured pins as GPIO OUT for the ones I talked about. I mean for the exact configuration I find some pins not working

Comment: C14 and C15 are not necessarily connected to CN7. It depends on the revision of your board and how some solder bridges are configured. See section 6.9 of the [user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Comment: "_Obviously I configured pins..._"  - that is not at all obvious.  What perhaps  _is_ obvious is that any such initialisation is not correct it, which is why you were asked to provide it.  Either that or it is a hardware issue, which we can also not solve from that code fragment.  You would help yourself by taking advice and providing the requested information.  Just to respond with "_of course I did that_" comes across as somewhat arrogant, like you assume the fault is not with your code.

Comment: @امیرحسینمحمدامری the code shown is 100% useless for us. In can be replace by `Blink();` and you could ask the question why it is not working

Comment: @Clifford don't be angry at me. I said that I am totally beginner and I might say sth silly. the point is that I mentioned that I tried the same thing for several pins (6 pins here) and when a person as beginner is comparing all pins together I suppose that I it obvious that he did exactly the same for all of them and he there might be something missing such solder bridges that he has no clue about. It would be silly that I configured 4 pins as output and they worked and I forgot to configure the rest to as output so they do not work.

Comment: @0___________ Bro, please forgive me about being so silly. hopefully my issue is not about code. I am asking that why this simple exam doesn't have the same output for all pins. am I missing sth?

Comment: @امیرحسینمحمدامری  `hopefully my issue is not about code`  What else? Compiler? uC?

Comment: I am not talking about configuring as output.  That is not the only required initialisation.  Each port has a separate clock enable in the RCC for example.  As you say you are a beginner; it is more likely that you will _code_ something incorrectly than it is you would "_say_ something silly".

Comment: Generally though if some one who is trying to help you on SO asks for further information or suggests that your question is somehow deficient, the response should be to update the question with the requested information rather then to just give an assurance that it is not the problem.  How do you know?  The problem is clearly _not_ in the code fragment you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO pins on STM32 are multiplexed to other on-chip peripheral functions, and may not all be available as GPIO on your particular board design.

As stated in the [manual for your board](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) section *6.7.2 OSC 32 kHz clock supply* PC14 and PC15 are normally unavailable as they are used for the 32.768KHz low-speed external (LSE) oscillator.  You can modify the board as described:

[image]

But any devices that utilise the low speed oscillator will then tun from the LSI which is very inaccurate.  That is generally not critical you are using the RTC (Real-time clock), which will mot maintain accurate time/date using the LSI.

PC12 is less easy to explain, the user manual no longer includes the board schematic as I am sure they used to, but the manual suggest sit is normally connected to the I/O connector. PC12 is multiplexed to `EVENTOUT` and `USART3_CK` but it seems unlikely that you have configure either of those functions.

The Nucleo boards have a built-in ST-Link debugger, so you are able to directly inspect the GPIO and RCC registers to see if they are configured as you expect. It is also possible modify the registers in the debugger, for example to directly set the pin state via the ODR while code execution is halted,